# Sending formatted html mail through linux

Tags: python, html, linux

I have a python 2.2 script that builds up an html string in the following manner:

```
html_string = ""
html_string = html_string + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
html_string = html_string + "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
html_string = html_string + "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">"
html_string = html_string + "<html>..."
html_string = html_string + "</html"
```

I then right this data to a file.
Then I run the following command:

```
os.system("mail -s \"<Subject>\" <my_email_addr> < /path/to/file/email_file")
```

I then receive an email, but it comes out all unformated. It shows all the html tags and such. How do I make it show the html as it should? I'm using outlook 2010 as the mail client btw.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess it depends on what `mail` points to.  On my Archlinux distribution, it's `heirloom-mailx`.  What distribution are you running, and how does the version of `mail` on that distro interpret standard input?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/how-do-i-send-html-email-using-linux-mail-command) which describes how to send HTML mail using various incarnations of `mail`.

This isn't so much a Python programming problem as a how-do-I-invoke-`mail`-to-send-HTML-mail problem.

Of course, you could just employ the [relevant Python library (email package)](http://docs.python.org/library/email) to do what you need to as well.

Comment: Ya, I used the python library package. Worked out well. Thank you.